# spring batch structure for parallel processing

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am seeking some guidance please on how to structure a spring batch application to ingest a bunch of potentially large delimited files, each with a different format.

The requirements are clear:

1. select the files to ingest from an external source: there can be multiple releases of some files each day so the latest release must be picked
2. turn each line of each file into json by combining the delimited fields with the column names of the first line (which is skipped)
3. send each line of json to a RESTFul Api

We have one step which uses a MultiResourceItemReader which processes files in sequence. The files are inputstreams which time out.

Ideally I think we want to have

1. a step which identifies the files to ingest
2. a step which processes files in parallel

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fun one. I'd implement a customer line tokenizer that extends `DelimitedLineTokenizer` and also implements `LineCallbackHandler`. I'd then configure your `FlatFileItemReader` to skip the first line (list of column names) and pass that first line to your handler/tokenizer to set all your token names.

A custom `FieldSetMapper` would then receive a `FieldSet` with all your name/value pairs, which I'd just pass to the `ItemProcessor`. Your processor could then build your JSON strings and pass them off to your writer.

Comment: Note: you shouldn't need an initial step to decide which files to process if you know the file name pattern they'll come in with. If you need more complex logic, I'd use a `Partitioner` and put the target filename in the execution context of each child step

Comment: Thanks for the answers which look good. I have found an example which illustrates the partitioning approach you mention: from the book spring batch in action https://github.com/acogoluegnes/Spring-Batch-in-Action/blob/master/sbia/ch13/src/test/resources/com/manning/sbia/ch13/partition/PartitionMultiResourceStepTest-context.xml

Comment: Great book! I have it at my desk

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you job falls into typical - **reader -> processor -> writer** category with writer being optional in your case ( if you don't wish to persist JSON before sending to RESTFul API) or you can call step to send JSON to REST Service as `Writer` if `Writer` is done after receiving response from service.

Anyway, you don't need a separate step to just know the file name. Make it part of application initialization code.

Strategies to parallelize your application are listed [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html).

You just said a bunch of files. If number of lines in those files have similar count, I would go by partitioning approach ( i.e. by implementing `Partitioner` interface, I will hand over each file to a separate thread and that thread will execute a step - **reader -> processor -> writer**). You wouldn't need `MultiResourceItemReader` in this case but simple single file reader as each file will have its own reader. [Partitioning](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning)

If line count in those files vary a lot i.e. if one file is going to take hours and another getting finished in few minutes, you can continue using `MultiResourceItemReader` but use approach of [Multi-threaded Step](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html#multithreadedStep) to achieve parallelism.This is chunk level parallelism so you might have to make reader thread safe.

Approach [Parallel Steps](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html#scalabilityParallelSteps) doesn't look suitable for your case since your steps are not independent.

Hope it helps !!